# Search in Laravel using routes instead of controllers

Tags: php, laravel, search, routes

This is my Laravel route where I am getting value from as 'q' from a form to perform search from quiz table.

```
Route::get('/admin/Searchquizzes',function ($q) {      

$quizzes = DB::table('quiz')
            ->leftjoin('category', 'quiz.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
             ->where('name','LIKE','$q')
            ->select('quiz.*', 'category.name As category_name')

            ->get();
$categories = DB::table('category')->select('id', 'name')->get();

return view('admin/quizlisting', ['quizzes' => $quizzes, 'categories' => $categories]);
)->middleware('auth')->name('admin.Searchquizzes');
```

This is code for my laravel Form to perform search ..

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is not working I don't know why, help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you're missing the closing `}` for the closure (function). How is it not working exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by my self :)

```
 Route::get('/admin/Searchquizzes',function (Request $request) {
//dd($request->q);

$quizzes = DB::table('quiz')
            ->leftjoin('category', 'quiz.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->where('quiz.name','LIKE',$request->q)
            ->select('quiz.*', 'category.name As category_name')
            ->get();

$categories = DB::table('category')->select('id', 'name')->get();

return view('admin/quizlisting', ['quizzes' => $quizzes, 'categories' => $categories]);

})->middleware('auth')->name('admin.Searchquizzes');
```

Here is my form , Now i can search quizes :)

```
<form method="get" action="{{route('admin.Searchquizzes')}}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu won't get that form value. You are not using `POST` method

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.Searchquizzes')">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Route :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::POST('/admin/Searchquizzes',function (Request $request) {
    //dd($request->q);

    $quizzes = DB::table('quiz')
                ->leftjoin('category', 'quiz.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
                ->where('name','LIKE','$q')
                ->select('quiz.*', 'category.name As category_name')
                ->get();

    $categories = DB::table('category')->select('id', 'name')->get();

    return view('admin/quizlisting', ['quizzes' => $quizzes, 'categories' => $categories]);

})->middleware('auth')->name('admin.Searchquizzes');
```

Comment: sir i need to search specific 'Quiz' from my search bar from an existing table of quizzes so i should use 'Route::get' instead of post plzz clear me if i'm wrong .. Your solutins giving erors  "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `quiz`.*, `category`.`name` as `category_name` from `quiz` left join `category` on `quiz`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` where `name` LIKE $q)" this is eror statement